# create custom event in javascript and trigger it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my problem,i have one google ad that expand on click and return when hit close button..but according to changed conditions what i want is to show expand first and close automatically after certain time and when ever it expanded it should close after certain time..i have done this with jquery but  it is refreshing the page for the first time can anyone one help..add is made by using google web designer

here is my jquery code i am sure it wont refresh page abut again it is doing it that's why I was thinking of making custom javascript event and trigger it (core javascript)

```
 <script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   setTimeout(function clo(){
     $j('#close_this').trigger('click');
      $j('#expanded-page').addClass('ed');
        },10000);
// above function to clpse it first time after 10 second

(function(){
      $j('.banner').click(function(){
       $j('#expanded-page').removeClass('ed');
         var cl_chk = $j('#expanded-page').hasClass('ed')
            if(!cl_chk){
             setTimeout(function clo(){
               $j('#close_this').trigger('click');
                 $j('#expanded-page').addClass('ed');
                  },10000)
         }
      })
      })()

   //this function is for closeing that expando ad after its expanded
        </script>
```

here is the url demo:

[demo link asian paints ad](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/dalit-kids-death-seven-of-a-family-held-we-were-attacked-says-mother/?google_preview=XRvBVKL76c4YxJunsQUwxLfcuAWIAYCAgKDTycfB-gE&iu=1050432&gdfp_req=1&lineItemId=146693792&creativeId=75737855672)

Answer (score 0):

dont know if this can help

```
jQuery.noConflict() // no need to declare a global variable for jQuery ...

(function ($j) { // ... cause you can pass it here

  // i like to declare things once and for all....
  var closeAfter10 = function () {
    setTimeout(function clo() {
      $j('#close_this').trigger('click');
      $j('#expanded-page').addClass('ed');
    }, 10000);
  }

  //this will attach the event and start the countdown when all contents on the page are loaded
  $j(window).load(function() {
    $j('.banner').click(function () {
      $j('#expanded-page').removeClass('ed');
      var cl_chk = $j('#expanded-page').hasClass('ed')
      if (!cl_chk) {
        closeAfter10(); // ... so i can use them this way ...
      }
    });

    closeAfter10(); // ... here another use of that thing
  );

})(jQuery);
```